# Custom email based login to website implementation

Tags: php, email, authentication, web

I am a sort of a beginner in website development and a new user to SO. Here is what I want to implement for a client. They use gmail custom-email app as their corporate email. They want to restrict access to their website private area for users with an email account with their company (which is actually a gmail account). Something like what we have for login into SO. Only SO would allow any gmail/yahoo etc user to login but they want only ppl with their custom gmail email id.

Comment: Why not just allow them to use the Gmail login?  Do they use Gmail, or this "custom app"?  And if they use some "custom app", why doesn't it use the Gmail authentication?  It has to at some point...  Or, are you saying you are trying to restrict access that isn't related to Gmail at all?

Comment: the email ids are gmail-custom emails (like someone@company.com) but a gmail id. They want ppl to be able to login to the website but not any gmail user should be able to login.. only those on XXX@company.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I would probably rock it so that registration requires an @yourcompanydomain email.  Neglect the gmail factor, and focus more on the syntax of the email address being registered.  Then, require email verification.

I ran a similar script for our employee perks portal, simply checked on registration for @mycompanydomain in the email.  If it didn't exist, they can't proceed.

Comment: sounds like what i could use. but how do i check if that email id exists and they have the right password for that email ??

Comment: Hmmm.  I didn't realize we were trying to sync the passwords.  That's a different ball game.  So here's the Google login API:  http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html  What you're going to have to do is restrict login on layer 1 of this API, before the request is even sent to Google, from logins not @yourdomain.  I would just use a javascript to do this on form submit validation.  This is NOT fool proof by any means (disabling javascript), but there's not much you can do to mess with Google at the beginning of the login process.

Comment: In my opinion, the right and most secure way to do this would be to pre-populate your app with allowed logins or at least restrict to your domain at level 7 of the interaction sequence.  This would involve some server-side scripting for you.  If it's out of your realm, check with freelancer or rentacoder  or one of the SO job sites.  You'd essentially want the Google returned authentication to check against your allowed domains.  I would probably do this in PHP.

Comment: thanks nicole for your suggestions.. i will def go thru this stuff in a while and let you know.. you have given me a direction :)

Comment: hey this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.. My first post on SO and it got answered within an hr. You rock!!

Answer (score 0):

This is typically implemented with [OpenID](https://github.com/openid/php-openid).

Depending on your account configuration, you could also use IMAP or POP3, but OpenID will be far more flexible, as it won't depend on specific settings for each user account.